# Scala Futures - java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, concurrent.futures

I have a spark application that processes many spark jobs at the same time using scala futures, I used to have a pool with 5 threads but was necessary to increase this pool to 15 threads and I started to have an error: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

my code:

```
object TableProcessorWrapper extends SparkSessionWrapper {

  def main(args: Array[String]): List[Unit] = {

    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool(15))

    val dynamodb = DynamodbOperations()

    val tables = dynamodb.getTablesToProcess(args(0), "table")

    val processors = for {
      table <- tables
    } yield Future {
      TableProcessor(table).start(spark)
    }

    for {
      processor <- processors
    } {
      processor.onComplete {
        case Success(value) => println("Finished Processing")
        case Failure(e) => {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage)
          e.printStackTrace()
        }
      }
    }

    Await.result(Future.sequence(processors), Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

Could you help me how to solve this? I don't have idea how to start.

Thank you, so much!

Comment: The number of futures that you are creating is equal to the number of tables present in this case. And as a result, you don't have threads available in your thread pool, as all the other threads are busy.

Comment: No I have more than 30 tables, and this job work most part of the time, this error happens only sometimes.

Comment: but the new futures will wait for a thread to be available?

Comment: You can explore to use Future.traverse